# No subcategories needed

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am new to Pivot table. I have a simple table with 5 columns. I am creating Pivot table with just 3 columns:CustID,Name,sales.
I want all these as separate columns but it is showing as Name a subcategory of OrderID. I dont want that.I want them t be shown as two separte columns.
TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to display your pivot in tabular view.

see image below to find options for this.

I usually turn off subtotals when using this view also.

[image]

Comment: I did that and it looks like this:

Comment: how do i send an image?

Comment: add it to your question, show what you have, and what you want to achieve